# JQuery UnBind Works, Attempt to "re" bind does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, unbind

I'm working my way through a JQuery Solution and for the most part it works but I"m stumped on seemingly a small detail I know I'm overlooking. Heck, maybe my implementation/approach needs to be reconsidered.

Here's the flow of what works.
1. Click an anchor that adds  to a table.
2. Add CSS Class.
3. Disable (Unbind) click on  after preappend().
4. From the table of dynamically added record remove table based on ID.
5. delete class that was added in step 2.
6. Bind 'click'

However, although I can bind the click and alert on it. The expected functionality does not allow me to step through the above process again.

The code in question:

HTML SAMPLE:
link that starts the process:

```
<a href="#" class="view-carrier-scorecard"></a>
<a href="#" class="view-carrier-trend"></a>
<a href="#" class="view-carrier-insurance"></a>
<a href="#" id="17053942" class="add-carrier-company"></a>
```

table that holds new records after click of link

```
<table id="carrier-table"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

JQUERY and Custom Javascript Function

```
   <script type="text/javascript" id="removeCarrier">
     function removeCarrierFromList(obj) {
       var i = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
       document.getElementById('carrier-table').deleteRow(i);
       $('a#' + obj.id).removeClass('delete-carrier-company');
       //alert(obj.id); //.hasClass('add-carrier-company').tostring() ); //

       $('a#' + obj.id).bind('click', function() {
          //alert('User clicked on ' + obj.id);
       });
     }
   </script>



 <script type="text/javascript" id="carrierListJS">
    $(function() {

      // Link
      // This adds a carrier to a list
      $('.add-carrier-company').click(
      function() {

        var target = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(target);
        $("#carrier-table").prepend("<tr id='carrierRow_" + target + "'>" +
       "<td><a href='#' id='" + target + "' class='delete' onclick='removeCarrierFromList(this)'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td>" +
       "<td class='carrier-list-text'>" + target + " " + $("#name_" + target).val() + "</td>" +
      "</tr>");

        return false;
      });

      $('.add-carrier-company').click(
       function() { $(this).addClass('delete-carrier-company').unbind('click'); }
      );

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: FYI, if you just hit enter/return it won't create a new line. You have to add two space to the end of the line above or hit enter/return twice. Be sure to check the post preview below the question textarea to see what it will look like when it's posted. For more info on that click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or click the `?` button above the post textarea.

Comment: Won't this code end up creating 2 anchor tags with the same ID? Your initial add-carrier-company tag will have an ID of 17053942, and the anchor tag prepended into the table will also have that same ID, right? Perhaps the issue is attempting to bind an event based on the ID selector when two elements have the same ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues I noticed with the code. For one thing, as @RussellUresti mentioned, you create two tags with the same ID. For another thing, if you're using ID's in a selector in jQuery, don't include the tag name, just use the id (ie. use `$('#id')` not `$('a#id')`) it will be faster (it won't break your code though).

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5YNK/1/) to answer your question (though I rewrote most of it). :) I think it's what you're looking for.

Here's the code:
**Test HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="view-carrier-scorecard">aa</a>
<a href="#" class="view-carrier-trend">bb</a>
<a href="#" class="view-carrier-insurance">cc</a>
<a href="#" id="10002" class="add-carrier-company">10002</a>
<a href="#" id="10003" class="add-carrier-company">10003</a>

<table id="carrier-table" style="border:1px solid #000"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function addCarrier() {
    var target = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#carrier-table").prepend("<tr id='carrierRow_" + target + "'>" + "<td><a href='#' id='a" + target + "' class='delete'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td>" + "<td class='carrier-list-text'>" + target + " " + $("#name_" + target).val() + "</td>" + "</tr>");
    $('#a' + target).click(removeCarrierFromList);
    $(this).addClass('delete-carrier-company').unbind('click');
    return false;
}

function removeCarrierFromList() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('id').replace("a","");
    $this.closest('tr').remove();
    $('#' + id).removeClass('delete-carrier-company').click(addCarrier);
}

$(function() {

    // Link
    // This adds a carrier to a list
    $('.add-carrier-company').click(addCarrier);
});
```

Comment: Well done!! Thanks for taking the time to answer. Only been doing jquery for 2 weeks and your community involvment is much appreciated by developers like myself. Now I will look more indepth at your solution to learn from my mistakes. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, after looking at your code. Am I understanding it correctly that you are using JQuery Delegates?

Comment: i should correct myself, not the delegate function of jquery but passing in a function as a parameter.

Comment: @Jose Quinones: It's kind-of similar to delegates. Basically, in JavaScript (it's not jQuery specific), everything is treated as an object, including functions. So, this means that you can assign functions to variables and even pass them into functions. When call a function in jQuery that has a callback, it assigns the function you pass to a variable and calls it when appropriate. Normally you'd create an anonymous function (ie. `$.dosomething(function() { /*do stuff*/ });`) which means it has no name, but you can create named functions and pass them instead.

Comment: This allows you to write one function and reference it in multiple places (rather than writing multiple anonymous functions with the same content).